# Having both stretch and vertical align center with Bootstrap and flex?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have two divs. One that has top and bottom padding and the other that needs to inherit that padding/height. I know flex has an option stretch. But I also need the items inside that second div to be vertically centered. However, I can't get it to work. I'm using Bootstrap 4 and this is the rough outline of my HTML:

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.first {
  background: red;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.second {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row no-gutters align-items-stretch">
    <div class="col-md-6 first align-items-center">
      <h1 class="mb-0">Text goes here</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 second align-items-center">
      <h5 class="mb-0">Text goes here</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I've used `align-items-stretch` on `row` and I've tried to align the items vertically using `align-items-center`, but it obviously does nothing. What am I missing/doing wrong? Can someone please take a look?

Thank you!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would like the second (green) element to be the exact same height, padding and appearance for the text as the first (red) element? As far as I can [tell](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), Flexbox's stretch property is mainly for stretching elements vertically when these are positioned horizontally next to one another.

Comment: Exactly, I'd like it to be the exact same height and its content to be vertically centered! Is there a way I can achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems that your second div don't have the "flex" behaviour to make it works. Optionally, you can add: "align-items" to force it.

```
.second {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; // if not working by itself
}
```

Comment: I tried here. Seems to do the job ? https://codepen.io/adrienpierrewv/pen/abbmZgE